# Error in building Qt 5.0.0 win7 msvc2010-64 -icu

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, windows-7, build

I am building Qt 5.0.0 from source for msvc2010-64 bit with icu & opengl desktop. But same error kept repeating:

```
tools\qcollator.cpp(47) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: ‘unicode/
utypes.h': No such file or directory

tools\qstring.cpp(3841) : warning C4309: ‘argument’ : truncation of constant value
tools\qstring.cpp(3842) : warning C4309: ‘argument’ : truncation of constant value
qstringbuilder.cpp
Generating Code…
jom: G:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0\qtbase\src\corelib\Makefile [debug-all] Error 2
jom: G:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0\qtbase\src\Makefile [sub-corelib-make_first] Error 2
jom: G:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0\qtbase\Makefile [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
jom: G:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0\Makefile [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

I wonder why `utypes.h` file cannot be located. As I have already added the `icu\include` and `icu\bin64` to path, and can't figure out why it still fails.

Installed:

1. Active Perl 520
2. ICU 4c-49_1_2-win64msvc2010
3. Python 278
4. jom

My configuration:

```
configure -debug-and-release -opensource -icu -opengl desktop
```

Thanks much for any help!!

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `-I %ICU%\include -L %ICU%\lib64`

```
configure -debug-and-release -opensource -icu -opengl desktop -I %ICU%\include -L %ICU%\lib64
```

Comment: I'm also running into similar issue but its on Linux, Can you let know how can I do that on red hat linux. I actually get `The ICU library support cannot be enabled` when I run the configure with `-icu`